# how can I show color of RGB triplet format in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I have a question in matlab
I need a simple code in matlab to `get (R,G,B)` and show the color of that.
For example `get (1,0,0)` and show `red color`. How can I do ?

Comment: see my answer below . hope this help you..

Comment: thanks alot.it's work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Example

To change the background color of a figure to green, specify the color with a `short name`, a `long name`, or `an RGB triplet`. These statements generate equivalent results:

```
whitebg('g')
whitebg('green')
whitebg([0 1 0]);
```

You can use ColorSpec anywhere you need to define a color. For example, this statement changes the figure background color to pink:

```
set(gcf,'Color',[1,0.4,0.6])
```

for more detail visit this  http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

Comment: @M.B glad to help you.